# How to conditionally select rows from a variable calculated from two columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am very new to Python, and this feels as if it would have a very simple answer, but I have not been able to figure it out. I am trying to print only True rows from a Boolean variable calculated using two columns in a dataframe. Below is an example of the output I have, but I only want True values to return.

The last 4 lines of the input code contain what I have been trying, and it returns with the following ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

In SQL what I am trying to do would look something like: Select * From table Where rows='True'

Thank you for the help!

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['TTWO','ROKU','PERI'])
for i in range(range):
    df.loc[['TTWO'],i]=si.get_live_price('TTWO')
    df.loc[['ROKU'],i]=si.get_live_price('ROKU')
    df.loc[['PERI'],i]=si.get_live_price('PERI')
    a = df.iloc[:,-1]
    b = df.iloc[:,-2]
    a_minus_b=((a-b)/b)*100
    d = a_minus_b >= 0  
    if d == True:        #What I have been trying
        print(d)
    else:
        print('no significant results')
```

Example Output if I just ended the code at print(d) (no if statements):

```
TTWO  False
ROKU  True
PERI  False
```

Comment: If it's in a daframe just do true_list = df[df['column_name'] == True]

Comment: @DavidE Thanks for the reply. That is where I get lost. If i create  variable1 by multiplying column1 times column2, for example, is variable1 considered to be in the df itself?

Comment: If you can put the snippet of the input & expected output as text, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: @SH-SF good advice, didn't know it was so easy. Thanks

Comment: You have just put the index of your dataframe, can you plese put some data of the dataframe as well? It can be dummy which results in what you are trying to do.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['TTWO','ROKU','PERI'])
d = []
for i in range(range):
    df.loc[['TTWO'],i]=si.get_live_price('TTWO')
    df.loc[['ROKU'],i]=si.get_live_price('ROKU')
    df.loc[['PERI'],i]=si.get_live_price('PERI')
    a = df.iloc[:,-1]
    b = df.iloc[:,-2]
    a_minus_b=((a-b)/b)*100
    d.append(a_minus_b >= 0) 
df['somename'] = d
print(df[df['somename'] == True])
```

here I printed your expected result but you can do whatever.
Hope it helped

Comment: This certainly helps put me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this may be what you need.
If you ahve a dataframe as below

```
        A   B   C   D
TTWO    2   12  52  50
ROKU    3   13  55  60
PERI    4   14  73  70
```

Use the below code

```
(((df['D']-df['C'])/df['C'])*100)>=0
```

**Output**

```
TTWO    False
ROKU     True
PERI    False
```